# Problems accessing directories outside of the rails app but on the same server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This may be a fairly simple problem to answer but I have not found a solutions from my searches. I want to access files in a folder that is outside of my rails app directory, for example I have a folder at:

> /media/Files/

and my rails app is in the directory

> /media/rails_app/app

But I would like to load a file in my rails app from the Files directory. I have tried several things like backticks

> ../../Files/image.jpg

and directly linking to the file but this has not worked. Is this even possible or is impossible because of security issues? The files are on the same server so I am not sure why this would be a problem but I have not seen a way to get it to work. I would prefer not to have to include all of these files in the actual app in the /public/images. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your rails process runs as a user that doesn't have access to that file? Whenever I need to specify a path in rails I always use Rails.root to get a real absolute path and then work from that.

Seems to work to read outside the rails dir

```
IO.read('/tmp/foo.txt')
 => "adf\n"
```

Specifying absolute path

```
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 :002 > File.join(Rails.root, '..', 'bar', 'foo.img')
```